# Quicksort in C++keeps giving me disorder in .log file

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, sorting

For my class project, we were tasked to choose an algorithm and implement it using thread from C++. I use a different file to generate random numbers and I then run quicksort using a .sh file that writes the runtime of the algorithm and I keep on getting disorder. When I look at my .out file that's supposed to have the elements sorted, it sorts them and then starts over again. For example, it will go from 101->999 then start again 101->999 which I'm assuming is because there's a problem with how I'm merging the file. I keep looking at the code and can't see what's going on. If someone could help me correct this issue or point out where it's wrong, I would appreciate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 1000000;
const int THREAD_COUNT = 12;

void QuickSort(int* array, int left, int right) {
  int i = left, j = right;
  int pivot = array[(left + right) / 2];

  while (i <= j) {
    while (array[i] < pivot) i++;
    while (array[j] > pivot) j--;
    if (i <= j) {
      swap(array[i], array[j]);
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }

  if (left < j) {
    QuickSort(array, left, j);
  }
  if (i < right) {
    QuickSort(array, i, right);
  }
}

void Merge(int* array, int size, const vector<int>& sizes) {
  int* temp = new int[size];
  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
    copy(array + index, array + index + sizes[i], temp + index);
    index += sizes[i];
  }
  copy(temp, temp + size, array);
  delete[] temp;
}

void SortThread(int* array, int left, int right, vector<int>* sizes) {
  QuickSort(array, left, right);
  sizes->push_back(right - left + 1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int array[SIZE];
  int size = 0;
  int num = 0;
  ifstream fin(argv[1]);
  while (fin >> num && size < SIZE) {
    array[size] = num;
    size++;
  }
  fin.close();

  vector<thread> threads;
  vector<int> sizes;

  int chunkSize = size / THREAD_COUNT;
  int left = 0;
  int right = chunkSize - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
    if (i == THREAD_COUNT - 1) {
      right = size - 1;
    }
    threads.emplace_back(SortThread, array, left, right, &sizes);
    left = right + 1;
    right = left + chunkSize - 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
    threads[i].join();
  }

  Merge(array, size, sizes);

  ofstream fout("mysort.out", ofstream::out);
  if (!fout){
    cerr << "Error" << endl; 
    return 1; 
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    fout << array[i] << "\n";
  }
  fout.close();

  return 0;
}
```

I've tried different ways of merging the threads together and rewritten the code multiple times but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your program writes to memory while other threads read or write from/to the same memory. This data race makes the program have undefined behavior - which means that the result can be pretty much anything.

The one I could spot right away is that you do `sizes->push_back(right - left + 1);` in the threads without making sure that each thread is alone doing it.

You could assure mutually exclusive access to `sizes` by using a `std::mutex`:

```cpp
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mtx;
void SortThread(int* array, int left, int right, std::vector<int>& sizes) {
    QuickSort(array, left, right);

    std::lock_guard lock(mtx); // now only one thread at a time can update `sizes`:
    sizes.push_back(right - left + 1);
}
```

Note that I take `sizes` by reference instead since a `nullptr` shouldn't be allowed. That also requires that you package it in a `std::reference_wrapper` at the call-site:

```cpp
threads.emplace_back(SortThread, array, left, right, std::ref(sizes));
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You may have other similar issues - and the fix is the same. Protect the data so that no thread can read/write data while another thread is updating it. If you are using `clang++` or `g++` you can compile with the ThreadSanitizer library to get data race checks at runtime. Add the compiler options:

```
-g -fsanitize=thread
```

---

When that has been fixed, then yes, your `Merge` function doesn't actually merge the ranges. It just copies each range into the `temp` array and then copies the result back into `array`. The final result is therefore exactly the same as the input.

You need to copy the value from the range that has the smallest value and keep going until all ranges are depleated.

It could look like this:

```cpp
void Merge(int* array, std::size_t size, const vector<int>& sizes) {
    std::size_t index = 0;

    // begin and end iterators for the ranges:
    std::vector<std::pair<int*, int*>> its;
    its.reserve(size);

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
        its.emplace_back(array + index, array + index + sizes[i]);
        index += sizes[i];
    }

    auto temp = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(size);

    for(int* out = temp.get(); not its.empty(); ++out) {
        // find the iterator pointing at the smallest value
        auto smallest = std::min_element(its.begin(), its.end(),
                                         [](const std::pair<int*, int*>& lhs,
                                            const std::pair<int*, int*>& rhs) {
                                             return *lhs.first < *rhs.first;
                                         });
        *out = *smallest->first; // copy the smallest value to temp

        // step the iterator and if it reaches the end, remove it:
        if(++smallest->first == smallest->second) its.erase(smallest);
    }

    std::copy(temp.get(), temp.get() + size, array);
}
```

Comment: This was perfect, thank you for helping me out!

Comment: @StephenMartinez You're welcome! I see that you've accepted an answer to another question you asked so I wonder if there's anything I should add to this answer to make it acceptable too?